# EndPrint event System.Drawing.Printing

Tags: c#, printing

I am printing using methods available in the older `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace because the `PrintDocument` object provides a `PrintPage` event which allows me to load an image and dispose of it instantly. Trying to print using a FixedDocument would often result in out of memory conditions.

I have however hit a strange problem - i use the `EndPrint` event handler to close my printing application once it has spooled the pages. If i just call `Close()` my print documents sometimes come out missing pages or the printer outputs obscure (Timeout/Syntax) errors.

The workaround i have at the moment is a bit of a hack which involves calling `Hide()` and then waiting an arbitrary amount of time (in my case 30 seconds) before closing it, this seems to work.

I really dont like this approach - how do you know how much time to wait? Shouldnt the EndPrint ensure that the last page has spooled?

Anyone have ideas for a "proper" fix? Or explain what is going on?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this event to catch the end of printing. I have achieved the correct completion of the application through an asynchronous print call and waiting for it to complete through the Wait method of the class
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.

```
// Start print asynchronously
System.Threading.Tasks.Task PrintTask = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(new Action(PD.Print));
PrintTask.Start();
// Wait
PrintTask.Wait();
// End of application
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```